# How to make this code accept an input

Tags: java

I have been trying to find a way to make my code which does exponents accept an input for E and X. I know that if I use the scanner util, it would make this possible. But so far, I haven't found a way to do that. If you could help that would be sweet, thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleExponents {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int e = 6; 
    int x = 4; 
    double result; 

    result = Math.pow(e,x);

    System.out.println( result );

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int e = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
int x = Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
```

or

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int e = scanner.nextInt();
int x = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: To expand on answer for OP, also possible to use `System.out.print("Input a value for 'e':\t");` before to prompt for an answer. +1, flkes.

Comment: Thanks bro's you are a great help!